# Como assinar arquivo .jar com certificado A3?

Tags: java, certificado-digital, jar, applet

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web e precisei desenvolver um `applet` com a linguagem `Java` para algumas funções.

Os navegadores estão reclamando da questão de segurança e, pesquisando, descobri que tenho que assinar digitalmente o arquivo `.jar`. Ainda pesquisando, verifiquei que posso fazer uma auto-assinatura, mas o navegador ainda poderá reclamar.

Tenho um certificado digital `A3` e gostaria de assinar o `applet` com ele, porém não consigo acessá-lo com os métodos indicador na `keytool` e no `jarsigner`.

Como posso assinar este arquivo utilizando um certificado `A3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Primeiramente, precisamos criar um arquivo de configuração que determinará a localização do driver do Token ou Smartcard. Crie um arquivo de nome *token.cfg* na sua pasta de trabalho.

A seguir temos o conteúdo que deve ser colocado neste arquivo. Os campos *name* e *description* podem conter um texto de sua escolha, mas o campo *library* deve apontar para a localização do driver do dispositivo.

> name = Provedor
>   description = Token Pro Azul
>   library = /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so

Para utilização no Windows o campo *library* deve conter o caminho da *dll* referente ao *driver* do token como o exemplo abaixo:

> name = Provedor
>   description = Token Pro Azul
>   library = C:\Windows\System32\eTPKCS11.dll

O Token ou Smartcard pode conter um ou mais certificados, cada um deles associado a um apelido. Antes de iniciarmos a assinatura, precisamos descobrir qual o apelido do certificado que será utilizado para a assinatura. Para isso, vamos executar a linha de comando a seguir. O campo PASSWORD deve ser substituído pelo seu Pin.

> keytool -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg token.cfg -storepass PASSWORD -list

Após a execução deste comando, será exibido a lista de apelidos. abaixo temos um exemplo do resultado esperado.

> (eTCAPI) HUMBERTO DE MELO PACHECO's ICP-Brasil ID

Podemos agora proceder para a assinatura do artefato utilizando a linha de comando abaixo. Os parâmetros a serem alterados são os seguintes.

- PASSWORD, o Pin do Token ou SmartCard.
- DSANAME, o nome do arquivo que contém as assinaturas das classes. Este atributo é opcional.
- JARFILESIGNED, o nome do arquivo gerado após a assinatura.
- JARFILE, o nome do arquivo a ser assinado.
- ALIAS, o apelido do certificado a ser utilizado, obtido no passo anterior.

> jarsigner -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg token.cfg -storepass PASSWORD -sigfile DSANAME -signedjar JARFILESIGNED -verbose JARFILE "ALIAS"

Referências:
[Assinando um artefato com Token ou SmartCard - Demoiselle Framework](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/certificate/reference/1.0.2/html/assinatura-jar.html#d0e494)